# Action template not rendering after an ajax call in Rails 3.2.13

Tags: jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, unobtrusive-javascript, unobtrusive-ajax

I would like to perform an ajax request by passing some data from the browser (some text values as a string) and render view of the same action to which I am sending request using ajax.

My workflow goes like this:

1. User upload two files :calib and :inten.
2. app saves the file using    paperclip and parses the information in different instance variables.
3. Once the file is parsed app delivers the message in the form of `flash[:notice]` in create action and immediately make pr list available to the user as a drop down list in the browser.
4. There are    two partials `_form` and `_formTwo` which gets rendered in create    action.
5. when I perform ajax request, I am in create view, and I am    requesting other action named `norm` in the controller.
6. After the ajax call I want app to render the `norm.html.erb` without refreshing the page.

> My codes are here: http://pastie.org/private/keykmwbzcrv04dfvkufsew

I tried ajax using unobtrusive javascript but I dont know how to pass some data (mentioned above) using link_to or button_to helper.

With simple jquery ajax, I can pass data to the server but my page is not rendering. Development log shows that Page is rendered, but nothing changes in the browser page. I know I am missing something but unable to figure it out??

Development log output:

```
Started POST "/normalize" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-30 13:38:43 +0200
Processing by UploadsController#normalize as */*
Parameters: {"data"=>"17,Poly-T-CY5,EukS_1209_25_dT"}
Upload Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `uploads`.* FROM `uploads` WHERE `uploads`.`id` = 17 LIMIT 1
Rendered uploads/_normalize.html.erb (0.2ms)
Rendered uploads/normalize.js.erb (1.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 4ms (Views: 2.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)
```

I hope I have explained my problem well, please let me know if I have not made myself clear??

Answer (score 0):

Link_to allows you to pass it a data_hash as so:

```
<%=link_to("Link",link_path,:data=>{foo:"bar",hello:"goodbye"},remote:true)%>
```

Looking at your code, another problem is that the 'norm.html.erb' file is not a partial.  In order to render it from 'norm.js.erb' you need to rename it '_norm.html.erb' so rails will recognize it as a partial.

Comment: thanx for explaining...but I found a major hitch in my code and that's being dataType: 'string' in my ajax call which should be dataType: 'script'. I changed it and everything worked well. :)